# Is it acceptable to send APNS device token each time with user request instead of registering user?

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications, devicetoken

I have iOS application where new data arrives each hour on server.
When new data arrives, I would like to notify user if there is something of interest for him, based on his alert definitions.

I learned that only way to achieve that is APNS (Background tasks are not an option for regular precise waking up and fetching data so far I can tell after reading a lot).

I don't want to add registration/login requirements for user.

Is it possible and aligned with Apple standards to retrieve device token and send it to server each time with each alert request created by user, so that I can notify him/her by push notification once it is fulfilled?

So I can pair device token with alert request in database on server.

I don't want to implement apps feature and to go through effort of implementing APNS both client and server side only to get application rejected by Apple. Therefore, any reference to if it is possible or not, personal experience or working solution proposal is much appreciated.

Comment: APNS registers devices, not users. The user has to accept (once) to receive notifications, that's all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, iOS uses a UUID as "device token" and it changes frequently and randomly (to protect privacy) so unless your application handles users one way or another, you won't be able to pair users with devices.

A solution might be that when your application installs for the first time and opens, you generate a unique id, it can be a UUID or some random string and save it to the keychain or if possible loses are okay, just save it to userDefaults. Keychain persists between app install and even is the user switches phones and you can use this uuid as "user per device"

Comment: I will accept your answer as it stated obvious thing I missed - changeable device token, plus I believe offered solution suits my needs. Thanks!